# How can I prevent writing an additional line of code for each created ComboBox on first row of TableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I would like to create a ComboBox on first row of TableWidget. My code works so far but the problem is I have to write another line for each ComboBox for each cell. I use these ComboBoxes to categerize each column to retrieve data from these columns for calculation purposes. Is there any way to shorten the code? Many thanks in advance.

My Code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ComboBoxCategory(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("font-size: 13px")
        self.addItems(["","Customer-ID", "Customer Name", "Revenue", "Year", "Revenue Type"])

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(1700, 800)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        #****************   Table Widget  **********************#
        self.TableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.TableWidget.setRowCount(500)
        self.TableWidget.setColumnCount(26)
        self.TableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
        self.TableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 200)
        self.TableWidget.horizontalHeader().resizeSections()
        self.TableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 200, 1625, 500))
        # # # ************   Table ComboBox first row  ****************#
        self.combo0 = ComboBoxCategory(self.TableWidget)
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 0, self.combo0)
        self.combo1 = ComboBoxCategory(self.TableWidget)
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 1, self.combo1)
        self.combo2 = ComboBoxCategory(self.TableWidget)
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 2, self.combo2)
```

EDIT: Solved

```
  def Combobox(self):
        for column in range(2):
            combo_cell = "combo" + "0"
            self.combo_cell = ComboBoxCategory(self.TableWidget)
            self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(0, column, self.combo_cell)
```

Comment: Uhm... what's wrong with a simple `for column in range(8): ...`?

Comment: @musicamante Thanks a lot :) it worked. Sorry for asking stupid questions. I have a finance  background and trying hard to learn programming. So, slow learner here :D Is there any way that I can give your answers thumbs up. I am quite new here

Comment: You can upvote comments by clicking on their small grey up arrow (but since you're new I don't know if you need more reputation in order to do so), but that's it. As soon as you have questions that get answers you can upvote them. In the meantime I suggest you to [follow the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn more about [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) and more topics on the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).